# Compiler error: std::basic_ios<_Elem, _Traits>::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<_Elem, _Traits>::_Myt &)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Anyone come across this error before? I'm at a loss to what precisely could be causing this:

```
1>...include\sstream(640): error : "std::basic_ios<_Elem, _Traits>::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<_Elem, _Traits>::_Myt &) [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]"
1>...include\istream(922): error : "std::basic_ios<_Elem, _Traits>::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<_Elem, _Traits>::_Myt &) [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]"
1>...include\istream(18): error : "std::basic_ios<_Elem, _Traits>::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<_Elem, _Traits>::_Myt &) [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]"
1>...include\ostream(37): error : "std::basic_ios<_Elem, _Traits>::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<_Elem, _Traits>::_Myt &) [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]"
```

It doesn't give any indication of anything in my source code that could have caused this, and I have no idea what problem this error is pointing to (it just says `error`). I mean, I use streams, strings all over my source code, so can anyone hint at what could be causing this?

MSVC 2010, compiled using NVCC

Comment: Can you show the code it's trying to compile when this comes up? Perhaps look a few lines above this, it may show a line from your code.

Comment: Thanks, but these lines are the only lines causing trouble now - there are no more lines above it. I can post my source online, but honestly it's many thousands of lines long across many several files. I was just wondering if anyone had come across this one before.

Comment: @MiloChen So your compiler just randomly decided to throw those errors at you? You must've written some code that generated those errors. Please post that code.

Comment: I've just finished restructuring very large sections of code, where almost all files were changed, so I really can't pin it down to a specific change I've done recently. I've managed to resolve all compiler errors down to these last 4.

Comment: @MiloChen Which file was the compiler building when these errors came up?

Comment: Thanks - my `main` file. Yes, that's one way to go - I'll slowly move functions out of that file until the error comes from a different file.

Comment: @MiloChen: Are these messages in the "Error" window or the "output" window?  Because the "Error" window just has summaries, and the "output" window has all of the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of isolating the bug, I managed to resolve the issue: in case anyone comes across this error, the error is NVCC's way of complaining that you're implicitly copying a `std::stringstream` object, which is not allowed.

In my case, I had an exception class `myError` which contained a `std::stringstream` object deep down inside, and calling `throw myError(...)` implicitly caused an illegal copy to occur.

The full resolution is explained in [this separate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515644/stringstream-error-cannot-access-private-member-declared-in-class-stdbasic-i?answertab=votes#tab-top).