# Stringstream error: cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'

Tags: c++, stringstream

In creating a simple exception class extension (where I can construct error messages more easily), I've isolated an error down to the following simple code:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
class myCout {
public:
    std::stringstream ssOut;    // Removing this gets rid of error
    template <typename T> myCout& operator << (const T &x) {
        // Do some formatting
        return *this;
    }
};

class myErr : public myCout {
public:
    using myCout::operator<<;
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    throw myErr() << "ErrorMsg" << 1;
    myCout() << "Message Will Be Formatted";
    return 0;
}
```

Which, on compiling, produces this error:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\sstream(724): error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ios(176) : see declaration of 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'std::basic_stringstream<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::basic_stringstream(const std::basic_stringstream<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
```

(In actual fact it's more complex and extends stuff like `std::runtime_error`)

I have seen [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159196/cannot-access-private-member-declared-in-class-stdbasic-ios-elem-traits) which state the problem arises from not passing streams by reference, but I can't see how I'm not.

Commenting out the `std::stringstream ssOut` fixes the issue. Why, and how do I fix the underlying problem?

Comment: [This design works a little better](http://ideone.com/F9eutl)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're throwing the exception by value, which is indeed recommended practice. However, it means the exception gets copied as part of the `throw` statement, so it must have an accessible copy constructor. And because you have a non-copyable member (`std::stringstream`), you must provide your own copy ctor.

Comment: Or could I just declare the `stringstream` as `static` to prevent copying?

Comment: @MiloChen Well, this would mean all instances of `myCout` share the one stream, so you'd have to 1) clear it before each use, and 2) introduce some synchronization for mutlithreaded access. If you have C++11, you could sove 2) by making it `static thread_local`.

Comment: You could have a `stringstream` local to the function, and keep the results in a `string` member variable. I know it's less efficient, but throwing an exception should be exceptional. Or you could have a member pointer to a `stringstream`.